# WARN/InputManagerService(60): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 743

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, ddms

:(
Please help me, I get this error whenever I am trying to call a Camera Activity. Well, you see, I'm trying to combine my friend's activity with my activity. But when I try to call his activity, it just Force Closes. :(

I know there is nothing wrong with his code, I mean, he ran it as a different project and it worked as expected. I have copied and pasted his activity,xml and everything so it should be fine right? All I had to do was call his activity. I've also added the said activity to the manifest. But still nothing, I've been trying to debug this bizarre behavior for three days and it's bothering me too much.

Here are the contents of my logcat:

```
01-26 14:54:15.528: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43ffc1c8 bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice/.CameraActivity}
01-26 14:54:19.598: INFO/Process(743): Sending signal. PID: 743 SIG: 9
01-26 14:54:19.638: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Process bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice (pid 743) has died.
01-26 14:54:19.638: INFO/WindowManager(60): WIN DEATH: Window{4406b0f0 bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice/bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice.profileCreator paused=true}
01-26 14:54:19.658: INFO/WindowManager(60): WIN DEATH: Window{43f151e8 bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice/bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice.CameraActivity paused=false}
01-26 14:54:19.658: INFO/WindowManager(60): WIN DEATH: Window{43f98ed8 SurfaceView paused=false}
01-26 14:54:19.678: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Displayed activity bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice/.CameraActivity: 5210 ms (total 5210 ms)
01-26 14:54:19.758: WARN/InputManagerService(60): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 743 uid 10039
01-26 14:54:24.778: DEBUG/dalvikvm(237): GC_EXPLICIT freed 174 objects / 10880 bytes in 90ms
01-26 14:54:26.016: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43febbc8 bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice/.profileCreator}
01-26 14:54:26.029: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43ffc1c8 bukojuice.kiss.ass.bukojuice/.CameraActivity}
```

I hope someone can help me. It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably you'll have to post some code. Are you running this on a real device?

Comment: No, I'm running it on the emulator. :(

Comment: mmm the emulator doesn't have camera support. maybe it crashes because of that.